# Data log with Table View

Tags: ios, uitableview, logging

I'm creating a simple app that allows users to see how much money they have earned or spent. You click a button to add money and click other to withdraw money. [image: App itself]

I want to add a log to the app where the user can see when he spent money or earned money. So for example:

January 4th 18:50 -> +30€
January 4th 19:34 -> -67€

How would you do that? I mean, how could I get that data out and present it on a table view. I'm not asking for the code (that's the fun!) I'm asking the ideas, the concepts for making it. Thank you!

Comment: 1. Put all logs into object and push them to NSMutableArray - which probably you want to writeToFile.
 2. Display all logs using UITableView. Which part you don't know how to do ?

Comment: And how can I log the data? I mean, I can use NSLog to register every change and add the date, but... Can I create the NSMutableArray and set its values to the data from the NSLog?

Comment: What do you mean by "put all logs into object"?

Answer (score 1):

For such type of task I would use Core Data framework . Out there, especially in [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com) site there a lot of tuts about Core Data. In particular, I would use a `NSFecthedResultsController` that can be used with `UITableView` to show user logs. The fetched controller allows you to lazy loading rows and so to maintain a low memory footprint. Especially if logs become huge.

Obviously Core Data has a deep learning curve, so if you don't want to spend time for it, you could also use plain Sqlite wrapping it through [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). Or just use a plist file where you should write log.

About the formatting, I guess you have all the info to print what you want. If you have a plain text file, you should write the log as is. On the contrary, if you use Core Data/Sqlite, you should think to the attributes/columns you need.

Comment: I this will be more complex for me. But again, complex things are fun. I know the web you told me and I'm going to look for the Core Data tutorials there. So with Core Data I could get the info every time it's added (so if the user adds 5€, then it would be logged) or what?

Comment: @Bytes Yes. If you save it. ;) Core Data is a framework that manages object graph and, as secondary function, enables data persistence. Under the hood it uses, for example, Sqlite to save data. What type of log do you need?

Comment: What I need is to log the quantity the user entered and when did he enter it, so the user would be able to see it.

Comment: @Bytes So, Core Data could be the choice. Anyway in all cases, Core Data, Sqlite or plain file, you have to insert records explicitly. No automatic way.

Comment: So you mean that the user would have to add them? Can't I just log when the user enters the data and give it a date and use that?

Comment: @Bytes How? To make log visible to users you should save and then prepare data. And here the options.

Comment: @Bytes When an user interacts with your app, your code will manage the save and retrieve of logs. Does it work for you? This would be transparent to the user.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to use Core Data for this, thank you! :)

Comment: @Bytes do not forget to mark my reply as answered if helped you. Thanks.